# Check constraint on django

Tags: django, postgresql

I have two models

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ord_number:str
    ord_date: date
    ord_ref: str Null=True
    ord_qty: Decimal
    ord_desc: str
    timestamp: datetime
    created: datetime
    
    
Class OrderLines(models.Model):
    order: FK(Order)
    driver: FK(Driver)
    truck: FK(Truck)
    ord_qty: Decimal
    loaded_quantity: Decimal
    loading_date: date
```

My schemas on posting will be like this

```
OrderCreateBase = create_schema(Order, exclude=("id", "timestmap", "created"))
OrderLineCreateBase = create_schema(OrderLines, exclude=("id))

 class OrderCreateSchema(OrderCreateBase):
    order_lines = List[OrderLineCreateBase]
```

Json data to be used on creating like this

```
  "ord_number: "AB123",
  "order_date: Date(01/01/2021),
  "ord_ref" Null,
  "ord_qty": Decimal("10_000"),
  "ord_desc" "Sample Order",
  "order_lines"[
  {"order_id": 1,
  "driver_id: 23,
  "truck_id": 12,
  "ord_qty": Decimal("10_000"),
  "loaded_quantity": Decimal("8_000") <----#,
  "loading_date": Date(01/01/2021)},
  {"order_id": 1,
  "driver_id: 13,
  "truck_id": 17,
  "ord_qty": Decimal("10_000"),
  "loaded_quantity": Decimal("9_000") <----#,
  "loading_date": Date(01/01/2021)}]
  }
```

I want check constraint that will ensure total loaded quantity(`loaded_quantity`) per order will be <= to ordered_quantity (`ord_qty`)

currently my create endpoint is like this

```
@router.post(
    "/ilr/{ilr_id}/instrunctions",
    response={HTTPStatus.CREATED: Message, HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST: Message},
    tags=["ilrs instructions"],
    summary=_("create loading request instructions"),
    description=_("API to create ilr instructions lines"),
    url_name="create_ilr_instructions",
)
@transaction.atomic()
def create_ilr_instrunctions(request, ilr_id: int, payload: ILRLineCreateSchema):
    data = payload.dict()
    ilr = get_object_or_404(ILR, id=ilr_id, status=0)
    data["request"] = ilr
    data["order_date"] = ilr.ilr_date
    # get existing lines total volume
    total_volume = ILRLine.objects.filter(request=ilr).aggregate(total_volume=Sum("quantity"))
    if ilr.quantity < total_volume.get("total_volume") + data.get("quantity"): <-----#
        return HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST, {
            "detail": [{"msg": f"Total loading quantities will be higher than ordered quantity"}]
        }
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            ILRLine.objects.create(**data)

           .....
```

How can I force it on database level using check constraint? I don't want to override model save

Answer (score 0):

You can try [CheckConstraint.check](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.CheckConstraint.check)

```
from django.db.models import CheckConstraint, Q, F

class OrderLines(models.Model):
    ...
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(loaded_quantity__lte=F('ord_qty')),
                name='quantity_check'
            )
        ]
```

Comment: This will not work because it checks per line. But I want to check all lines referencing same order their total loaded qty to be less than or equal to ord_qty because all lines referencing same order will have the same ord_qty but each with it's own loaded_qty  `Line1 = OrderLine(ord_qty=1000, loaded_qty=500)`
  `Line2 = OrderLIne(ord_qty=1000, loaded_qty=800)` total loaded_qty(1300) must be less than ord_qty(1000)